# Does the canonical URL need to change for different parameters to a dynamic page that shows different content?

Tags: google, canonical-url, tags, dynamic

I have a page located at `example.com/tagged`, which shows posts that contain the selected tag for which a person has searched.

So, if someone searched for `#apple`, then `example.com/tagged/apple` would show all posts tagged with the `#apple` hashtag, and `example.com/tagged/orange` would show all posts tagged with the `#orange` tag. Simple enough.

Now, Google is telling me it needs a canonical URL. In my code, do I just add the canonical tag for each hashtag?

Meaning, should the canonical tag be dynamic, so that when someone searches for `#apple` the tag is

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/tagged/apple" />
```

and when someone searches for `#orange` it's

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/tagged/orange" />
```

Is this how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, canonical url should be different for different content.
Since you have pages for each tag, no matter if it processed by same script, canonical is different for each one.
If some keywords are aliases, they should have same canonical.